# How to loop through an array contained in a JSONb field?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, plpgsql

How do I loop through an array contained in a `jsonb` field inside a PLPGSQL function in Postgres 9.6?

This is my field declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE afact_rule(
    ...
    expressions         jsonb,
    ...
)
```

And this is my **FUNCTION** :

```
        FOR expression IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(rule.expressions) LOOP
            CASE expression.field 
                WHEN 'task_id' THEN
                    ... whatever ...
            END CASE;
        END LOOP;
```

And this is the error I get when using it:

> ```
> LINE 1: SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(rule.expressions)
>                       ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> QUERY:  SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(rule.expressions)
> ```

What is the best (and efficient) approach to loop through an array contained in a `jsonb` field?

The contents of the `rule.expressions` is:

```
 [{"field": "dep_id", "value": 1, "operator_code": 1},
  {"field": "title", "value": "customer", "operator_code": 2}]
```

Comment: `select * from "rule" r, json_array_elements(r.expressions)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, nope, doesnt work either. I think the error means there is no such function that accepts `jsonb` argument in Postgres. So, there must be some other function for `jsonb`

Comment: Ah, didn't see the `jsonB`. For that you have to use `jsonB_array_length` of course

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, but array_length will only return an integer, and I need an array for looping it through the `FOR` block. Do all the functions for `jsonB` have the `B` ending ?? Looks like undocumented feature.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , sorry, it is documented, I was looking at 9.1 documentation which shows up first in Google

Comment: I got over this error, but now I get another error accessing fields in expression: `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "expression"`

Comment: `select * from "rule" r, jsonb_array_elements(r.expressions)` you have to do a cross join between the table and the function

Comment: Your version of Postgres is *essential* for these questions. Please remember to declare it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [@a_horse commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837376/how-do-i-loop-through-an-array-contained-in-a-jsonb-field#comment70861291_41837376), use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) to unnest the `jsonb` array. Additionally I suggest `[INNER] JOIN` instead of a `CROSS JOIN`. `CROSS JOIN` is the verbose variant syntax variant of - and binds more tightly than - a simple comma (`,`):

```
SELECT * -- do something?
FROM   afact_rule a
JOIN   LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(a.expressions) exp ON exp->>'field' = 'task_id';
```

It should be most efficient to eliminate not qualifying elements (and rows) in the `JOIN` condition immediately. (The syntax is very clear, even if it results in the same query plan as a later `WHERE` condition anyway.)

The `LATERAL` key word is optional noise in this case, because it is assumed anyway for set-returning functions (SRF) in the `FROM` clause.

`exp` is the table *and* column alias for the result of the SRF function automatically here.

Related:

- [How to turn json array into postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)